# jQuery UI Slider Steps

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have a jquery UI slider and I have noticed that if the difference between max and min value is not an exact multiple of step option the slider doesn't works correctly.

For example:
min: 6900
max: 79900
step: 1500

When I move the max cursor, the maximum reachable value is 78900 ((78900-6900)/15=48), the next would be 80400.

How can I achieve the max value (79900)?

Thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4L0vtLd8/3/

Comment: As stated in jQuery UI Slider API, *The full specified value range of the slider (max - min) should be evenly divisible by the step.* (see http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-step)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set your max value to a multiple of step:

```
  var range = Math.floor((max - min) / step) + 1;
  var max_calc = min + range * step;
```

then in slide handler limit the values to original max value:

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
  var v1 = Math.min(ui.values[0], max);
  var v2 = Math.min(ui.values[1], max);
  $("#slider-price").slider("values", 0, v1);
  $("#slider-price").slider("values", 1, v2);
  $("#amount").val("$" + v1 + " - $" + v2);
}
```

Your fiddle adapted accordingly: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/d8wvke7u/